# How to replace all match string in android

Tags: javascript, android, regex

How to convert following javascript regex replace to andrjoid?

```
output =  output.replaceAll(/\u106A/g, " \u1009");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
output = output.replaceAll("\\u106A", "\\u1009");
```

Or this:

```
output = output.replace( "(\\u1031)?(\\u103C)?([\\u1000-\\u1021])\\u1064", 
       "\\u1064$1$2$3");
```

btw Javascript doesn't have any `replaceAll` method. You probably meant `String#replace` in JS.

Comment: How about this then, please? output =  output.replace( /(\u1031)?(\u103C)?([\u1000-\u1021])\u1064\g, "\u1064$1$2$3");

Comment: I updated the edit to show the Java syntax. Java doesn't need any `g` flag since we're using `replaceAll`